# How can I put image attached to comments to index.html.erb in songs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a comment in song, it has a one-to-many relationship, and each comment has an image,
I would like to put each image which have the best number of good in songs list.

```
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
        <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal1">
          <div class="portfolio-hover">
            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
              <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <%= image_tag song.comments.image.url(:medium).order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).limit(1) %>
          <img class="img-fluid" src="/assets/noimage.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="portfolio-caption">
```

But I get an error:

[image]

I do not know why image becomes a NoMethodError.
Also, the association between songs and comment should have been made.

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_votable
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_votable
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :song

has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "400x400#", :thumb => 
"180x180#" }, :default_url => "noimage.jpg"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

### How can I solve this?

```
NoMethodError in Songs#index
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">

         <%= link_to like_song_path(song), method: :put, class: "portfolio-link" do %>
          <div class="portfolio-hover">
            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
              <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x">
              </i>
            </div>
          </div>

         <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
         <%= image_tag song.comments.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).limit(1).first.image.url(:medium) %>
         <% end %>

          <% end %>
```

song.controoler↓

```
 before_action :set_song, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
 # GET /songs
 # GET /songs.json
 def index
 if params[:user_id]
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @songs = @user.songs.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)
 else
  @songs = Song.all.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)
 end
 end



private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_song
  @song = Song.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def song_params
  params.require(:song).permit(:title, :body, :get_upvotes)
end
```

I think the problem is @comments wasn't defined in index action.

I know I didn't define @comment in index action , but I'm not sure how to code.

Comment: The error you're seeing is due to `#image` being called on the collection of comments instead of an individual comment object. Try looping through the comments and calling `comment.image.url(:medium)`, similarly to how `@songs` is being iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're seeing is due to `#image` being called on the collection of comments instead of an individual comment object. Even though `#limit(1)` is being applied to the query, the returned result is still a collection. To fix the error, you can modify your existing query to the following:

```
<%= image_tag song.comments.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).limit(1).first.image.url(:medium) %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your helping.I added your code, and then stuck again with no method error.I will add my code and give me the tips if you can ,please.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<%= image_tag song.comments.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).limit(1).first.image.url(:medium) if song.comments.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).limit(1).present? %>
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you for your helping.I tried your code , but undefined method `each' appeared. I think the problem is not your code but @comment  isn't defined in controller.However I can't understand how to code.